# Iteration stops and throw "unsupported operand type" error

Tags: python, iteration, unsupportedoperation

I'm trying to iterate using a for loop over a dataset that contains 1 row and over 1500 columns (features). The features are tuples containing float objects. I can attach the csv file if not enough info is available to help. All I want to do is check whether a 1 is present under each column for the row. Any column containing a 1 will be sent to an empty list.

I understand (guess not as well as I thought) the core of the error that is being thrown (unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple') for executing the for loop below, but am not sure why it started to iterate for a subset of the data, and then threw the error.

```
for x in range(1,2):
peaks_to_delete = []   #empty list to add column labels (tuples)
index_to_delete = []   #empty list to add row
df1 = df_850.iloc[0]   #df_850 is dataframe
df2 = pd.DataFrame(df1)
df3 = df2.T
for col in df3:
    if sum(df3[col]) == 1:   #this is where it throws the error
        peaks_to_delete.append(col)
for index in df3.index:
    index_to_delete.append(index)
df_850.drop(peaks_to_delete, axis=1, inplace=True)   #drops the column from the dataset
df_850.drop(index_to_delete, inplace=True)   #drops the index (row label) from dataset
```

Is it because the iteration times out due to the number of data points? Again, if not entirely clear, I can add additional information.

I appreciate the help in advance!

Comment: Can you post df_850.head()?

Comment: how do I do that?

Comment: `print(df_850.head(10)` is the statement you need to execute.

Answer (score 0):

The data in the columns are tuples and not integers and you can't sum an array of tuples in that manner. If you want the sum of columns, sum the values in the tuples before summing the column.

```
if sum(df[col].apply(lambda x: sum(x))) == 1:
```

If you want to check if a certain column value contains `1`, you can check if 1 is in any of the tuples in the column values.

```
if any(df[col].apply(lambda x: 1 in x)):
```

If you want to check for any column values is equal to `1`

```
if any(df[col].apply(lambda x: x == 1)):
```

`any` in the example above returns `True` if any of the boolean satisfies your lambda expression.

Comment: Sorry I did a poor job of explaining the situation, but the data in the columns are integers and the column labels are tuples.

Comment: And you want to check if any of the column values contains `1` then append to `peaks_to_delete`?

Comment: Exactly, append the tuples (column names) to that list. It iterated for the first ~60 columns then stopped...

Comment: I edited my answer to include if any of the column values equal to `1`. If you want a more specific answer, please post an example of what your `df` looks like along with your expected outcome.

Comment: Ya this suggestion didn't work either. I appreciate the help tho. I'll try to get data posted.